# Couldn't start client Azure Resource Manager Template in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can someone please help to resolve this issue.

```
Error: Couldn't start client Azure Resource Manager Template in VS Code
[Error - 2:10:04 AM] Starting client failed
Error: spawn EPERM
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:403:11)
    at Object.spawn (child_process.js:562:9)
    at c:\Users\noohauqu\.vscode\extensions\msazurermtools.azurerm-vscode-tools-0.15.3\dist\node_modules\vscode-languageclient\lib\main.js:347:40
Error: ARM Template Language Server: An error occurred starting the language server.
```